# Android Bluetooth LE scanned devices missing Name

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, device-name

I've been using `StartLeScan` for quite a while, the names of the returned devices after a scan are never populated. I could never figure out why, I just get the mac address back.
Today I ran a scan from the OS BT settings page and it showed only the MAC addresses until the scan completed, then it showed the names. Now when I run a scan programmatically the names are always populated.

Why does StartLeScan not return the device names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name is not broadcast with the MAC during scan, the name you see later is a local cache after you have required it from the device.

My memory might be betraying me, but I believe settings makes a separate request for the name after they scan. Settings also has a local separate cache for keeping track of devices and their current state.

Remember that the name is not really a good way of identifying a device as it may be changed by the user.

Comment: Here's something interesting, if i call StartDiscovery() before StartLeScan() I will get the names returned in the LE scan. So I presume that a discovery requests the names and an LE scan doesn't

Comment: Yup, StartDiscovery is much more in depth but also takes longer and requires more resources. You shouldn't need both. Remember to call stopDiscovery when you find your device. You may want to look into the scan if you already know the MAC address you're going to connect to. Most Bluetooth chips are synchronous and will block for a good while if you attempt a connection to a device that's not available.

Comment: Is there a way to request the name without StartDiscovery? The name is useful for users when choosing a device to connect.

Comment: I believe the only other way is connecting. You can use characteristics in order to categorize devices for your users (may need a discovery).